# Wrong number of arguments for search

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA macro to automatically label each record in Sheet1 with the correct category based on Sheet2. However, I am getting this error:

> Run-time Error '1004': Invalid number of arguments.

When I debug, it seems to point to the line of code noted below.

The codes are as follow in a module tab:

```
Sub X()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim s As Variant

    For i = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count
        Dim arr() As String
        For r = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count
             ' the next line is where i get the error
             If Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("Sheet2!A$" & i & ",Sheet1!A" & r)) Then
                ReDim Preserve arr(i)
                arr(i) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 2)
            End If
        Next r
        For Each s In arr()
            Dim b As Long
            b = Application.Match(s & ",A1:M1")
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r - 1, b).Value = "Y"
        Next s
        Erase arr()
    Next i

End Sub
```

Sheet1 shows the special requests to be tagged/labelled with Y in the preceding columns

[image]
Sheet2 containing the primary keywords to search for and label the text in Sheet1 with Y if it is found

[image]

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: Hi Joseph! This line when I debug but I am not sure if there are multiple syntax errors elsewhere. 

If Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("Sheet2!A$" & i & ",Sheet1!A" & r)) Then

Comment: are you sure `Application.Search` is right? Maybe you meant `Application.Find` or `WorksheetFunction.Search`

Comment: Seems like Instr() would be the VBA way to go.

Comment: One of those returns a `Boolean` and the other returns a `Double` and you are using that result in a call to `IsNumeric` - so that doesnt make much sense. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi braX, I am trying to find if any primary keywords is found in the free text. If so, it will return a TRUE for me which I can then use an IF function to append the category topic into a list for tagging via MATCH() later on. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Application.SomeFunction` you should use the proper qualifier `WorksheetFunction` so you get the intellisense for the required parameters / arguments.

E.g typing `Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(` instead of `Application.Search(` will show that you need two string arguments in your `Search()` function, and you only provide one - but the one you provide does have a comma in it so I suspect you're joining the two arguments together in to one string by mistake.

You could try

```
("Sheet2!A$" & i, "Sheet1!A" & r)
```

In VBA this will become `(Sheet2.Range("A1"), Sheet1.Range("A9"))`

Instead of

```
("Sheet2!A$" & i & ",Sheet1!A" & r)
```

Which would resolve to `("Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A9")`

Note the difference - the latter is a single string which is trying to pass to `Search()` and the first is two separate `Range` arguments separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the line you hightlighted.

```
     If Application.IsNumber(Application.Search("Sheet2!A$" & i & ",Sheet1!A" & r)) Then
```

It appears:

```
Application.Search("Sheet2!A$" & i & ",Sheet1!A" & r)
```

requires two inputs. See link below

[expression.Search (Arg1, Arg2, Arg3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.search)

But, I could be wrong.
So the easiest way to debug would be to split up that line and see what is causing the error.

(1) Pull out this part of that line:

```
Application.Search("Sheet2!A$" & i & ",Sheet1!A" & r)
```

(2) Does that work? Does it return an argument that makes sense?

If not, fix that line. If so, move on to just the part below with a hardcoded input in the format from part 1 above. From there you can isolate which part of the line is giving you issues and verify each function is getting the right format input.

```
 Application.IsNumber()
```